# Sessions in Rails without separate view for signin/out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm a rails newbie with a conceptual question:

I want to implement a signin/signout mechanism. I'm currently following Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial. The thing is, that tutorial goes about implementing sessions with a separate controller and views. I want my signin form to be on the homepage (meaning, I don't want a sessions/new.html.erb page).

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I use a helper? a module? is it possible to achieve this using a SessionsController?

I'm swimming in new territory so any help (or examples) would be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

P.S. I'm using Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is usually done through partials. i just answered a question here that goes in the same direction: [Setting up routes incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206742/setting-up-routes-incorrectly/19207412)

you have your `home/index` action and your `home/index.erb` or whatever and you can include any file into this view. those are called partials and start with an underscore. if this piece of your view will get reused throughout your application, i usually create a `shared` folder and put all the helper partials in there. so like this:

```
|____views
| | |____users
| | | |____index.slim
| | | |____show.slim
| |____shared
| | |_____footer.html.slim
| | |_____headline.slim
| | |_____hint.html.slim
```

keep in mind that partials start with an `_` and you do a `<%= render('/shared/login') %>` if the file is `app/views/shared/_login.html.erb`

the next thing is that you want to keep your login logic in a `SessionsController`. that is a good thing! you just have to point your login form to the right route. run `rake routes` or point your browser to `/routes` when you are on rails4 to find out which route to point to. since it is usually the create action, you won't have any problems with using a HTTP post, as this is the default in rails. so it will be something like

```
<%= form_for sessions_path do |f| %>
```

always keep your development log open to find out where all your requests are going. i usually have one terminal window running a `tail -f log/development.log`.