# Setting up routes incorrectly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have created a simple users MVC where people can type in their email in order to join our mailing list. it seems to be working great. The only problem is I want to display the view on the Homepage. I am trying to simply put <%= render 'users/new' %> in my index.html.erb page but it keeps giving me an error

```
 Missing partial users/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb,       :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/jeff/Desktop/selfstarter/app/views"
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <%= render 'preorder/homepage/show_dont_tell' %>  
2: <%= render 'preorder/homepage/key_points' %>
3: <%= render 'preorder/homepage/other_points' %>
4: <%= render 'users/new' %>
5: 
6: <%#<%= render 'preorder/homepage/middle_reserve' %>  
7: <%#<%= render 'preorder/homepage/faqs' %>
```

I have heard I might want to make it into a partial but how do I convert my views into usable partials?

this is my routes file

```
    Selfstarter::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :users

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get "users/new"
  get "static_pages/about"
  get "static_pages/FAQ"

  root :to => 'preorder#index'
  match '/preorder'               => 'preorder#index'
  get 'preorder/checkout'
  match '/preorder/share/:uuid'   => 'preorder#share', :via => :get
  match '/preorder/ipn'           => 'preorder#ipn', :via => :post
  match '/preorder/prefill'       => 'preorder#prefill'
  match '/preorder/postfill'      => 'preorder#postfill'



end
```

this is my users_controller file

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Island Mailing List!"
      redirect_to root_path 
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

this is my user/new.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
<div class= "jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <div class="input-group">
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "YouEmailAdress@gmail.com" %>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= f.submit "Follow Project", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></span>
    <% end %>

                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!--/container -->
</div><!-- /jubotron -->





    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->


  <script src="../../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I believe it has everything to do with my routes and the way they are set up. I have been looking for a solution for this for a while. I have a feeling its really easy. As you can tell I am pretty new to ruby on rails.

Thank you!

model users

here is my model for users

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum:80 }, 
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end
```

Comment: I suppose this is a typo, but your partial should be in `users` not `user`, also, try changing its name to `_new.html.erb` - with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Partials must be prefixed with an underscore. This is a convention. So there should be a file named `_new.html.erb` in your `app/views/users/` folder.

Comment: It's not a convention; you *have* to do it.

Comment: that is actually not quite true, you could write your own resolver and tell rails to stfu. there are some very nice examples by jose valim in crafting rails applications: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/04/default-views-in-rails-3-0-with-custom-resolvers/

Comment: so when I change new.html.erb to _new.html.erb I get a new error stating undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class and it also says now even when I got to http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/new it says template missing. So how do I define a model so my index.html.erb views picks it up?

Answer (score 0):

rails is not really good in terms of error messages. like @Agis already answered, the real issue here is, that it is looking for a file starting with an underscore.

if you are using the `render` method within a view, it is looking for partials by default. have a look at the documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper/render

this is different from calling `render` in an action, where a view template will get rendered with a layout.

in any case, you would normally not just re-use a view as a partial. it's pretty uncommon to do that, so you extract some part of your view into a partial and re-use that, ie a login form or something like that.

i hope that helps you with a basic understanding of rails.

Comment: so when I change new.html.erb to _new.html.erb I get a new error stating undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class and it also says now even when I got to 0.0.0.0:3000/users/new it says template missing. So how do I define a model so my index.html.erb views picks it up?

Comment: your `@user` is because it is set in the `SessionController` i guess. you will have to set it in every controller you render that partial. the easy way would be to just set it in the form by writing `User.new` instead of `@user`